# How to trigger an on focus event for an HTMLEditorExtender

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor

I am using the HTMLEditorExtender that is part of the AJAX Control Toolkit, and I am trying to clear its text on focus.  But there is no `on-focus` event for it, and the basic jQuery won't work.

So my question is how do I trigger an on-focus event for an ASP.NET HTML editor?

Comment: Please provide the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide your html so this the best we can give you:

```
$('selector').focus(function(){alert('Works!');});
```

change the 'selector' to `Jquery` selector that fits your's element.